# Blob storage activation issue - Nopcommerce on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, nopcommerce

I am currently trying to activate Azure blob storage for my Web app (I am running NopCommerce 3.70).

I created the storage account on Azure and updated the values of AzureBlobStorage in the Web.config, however nothing seems to happen. The container of the blob is still empty and all thumbs are still being saved under ~/Content/Images/Thumbs.

My config is the following:

```
<NopConfig>
    <AzureBlobStorage ConnectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccountname;AccountKey=myaccountkey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" ContainerName="images" EndPoint="https://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/images" />
</NopConfig>
```

which is equivalent for Nopcommerce than writing this I reckon:

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccountname;AccountKey=myccountkey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" ContainerName="images" EndPoint="https://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/images" />
</appSettings>
```

Is there anything else to do that I missed?

Comment: Without seeing your web.config updates, you're only going to get guesses. Please edit your question to show your web.config settings (of course, don't show your real storage account name or key).

Comment: I realized it was too vague indeed. I did the edit, thank you.

Comment: Have you installed [nopCommerce Cloud Storage (Azure Blob/CDN, Amazon S3/CloudFront) plugin](http://shop.dev-partner.biz/nopcommerce-cloud-storage-azure-blobcdn-amazon-s3cloudfront-plugin)? And refer to this [video](https://youtu.be/Q0GKor_c8x8) for installing Azure Storage provider.

Comment: No I haven't, but normally Nopcommerce already provides this feature without the need of another plugin if I'm correct

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a demo site with nopCommerce 3.9 just fine. My config looks similar except the end point part.

Try using this (remove **images** at the end of endpoint)

```
<NopConfig>
    <AzureBlobStorage ConnectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccountname;AccountKey=myaccountkey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net" ContainerName="images" EndPoint="https://myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/" />
</NopConfig>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried it but it doesn't work unfortunately, the blob container is still empty when I'm uploading pictures and that thumbs are generated.

Comment: What media settings do you have? Check it at yourstore.com/Admin/Setting/Media

Comment: Pictures are stored into the database, but it doesn't work either when I choose the file system option.

Comment: Better to talk in chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155514/chat-for-question-46338774